# Access or list non media content from Download folder using SAF (Storage Access Framework)

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-11

I am trying to list **non-media** content from **Download** folder using **SAF**.

Sample Code:

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    // Provide read access to files and sub-directories in the user-selected
    // directory.
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
}
```

But when i open the Download Folder using SAF i see the "use this folder" button is disable.

I also noticed from the android documents they introduced new MediaStore.Download

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Downloads

i tried to use but i see the cursor count is zero. When should we use the above api ?

Comment: It is unclear what you do opening a folder using saf.

Comment: i gather non-media files like pdf and display the pdf in our app and can open pdf as well from the app as well

Comment: It looks as if you did not answer my question. I asked for the used code to open a folder.

Comment: i updated the body with sample code.

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` You can remove that as it makes no sense.

Comment: Please tell the value of `uriToLoad.toString()`. How did you obtain that uri? Does this initial uri work?

Comment: uriToLoad.toString() currently i m passing null  but previously i passed MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY) but i didn't see any difference yet. It still opens root folder in file explorer in both cases

Comment: `when i open the Download Folder using SAF` I still see nothing of a Download folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226581/discussion-between-abdul-and-blackapps).

Comment: This is a forum. No chat room.

Answer (score 2):

```
But when i open the Download Folder using SAF i see the "use this folder" button is disable.
```

It's because in Android-11, accessing Download folder through ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is restricted.

```
You can no longer use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access to the following directories:

The root directory of the internal storage volume.
The root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card is emulated or removable. A reliable volume is one that an app can successfully access most of the time.
The Download directory.
```

Reference
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#file-directory-restrictions

Comment: Is there an alternative to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` If I want to allow my users to use folders and look at content of files in those folder, including the `Download` folder, but my app is not a file explorer? I already have `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to show a picker but my users are picky as to how they want to see the files listed so I have my own explorer like activity to show them files inside a folder as well.